# Rewrite URL rule

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to simplify my URL. It should recognize each number by page=* and print it like this: localhost/cms_4/page/*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule cms_4/([0-9]+) cms_4/index.php?page=$1
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I wrote it the wrong way around.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule page/([0-9]+) index.php?page=$1
```

How can I redirect only the index.php file to page/* and not all other files and directories?